# 'Swift is not supported for static libraries' when creating a CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I created a skeleton pod with `pod lib create` and I am writing my code into the `Development pods > MyPod > Classes` group.

I am getting the error `Swift is not supported for static libraries`.

I haven't really edited any of the other files besides replaced the ReplaceMe.swift and added some others.

Here's the podfile:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyPod_Example' do
  pod 'MyPod', :path => '../'

  target 'MyPod_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths


  end
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out I should have read the tutorial better, it clearly says this:

> [!] Note: Due to a Development Pods implementation detail, when you
>   add new/existing files to Pod/Classes or Pod/Assets or update your
>   podspec, you should run pod install or pod update.

It helped with the very uninformative error.

Comment: while doing `pod install` or `pod update` make sure you are on correct path.

Comment: Update my pod but deleted my files in Development Pods folder after update pod.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar issue before. It is an issue with use_frameworks! that breaks for pods that have dependencies with static libraries.

Only solution for this that i found, after searching for quite a long while, was to remove all pods that use static binaries and try and find alternatives with dynamic frameworks.

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't using any other pods than my own

Comment: How did you fix it Nirri ?

Answer (score 0):

open ***project.xcworkspace*** file instead of ***project.xcodeproj***